# Python - How do I take the first 10 elements from a list and keep repeating?

Tags: list, repeat, element, items

I know this is probably quite simple, but I can't figure it out. I just want to take the first 10 elements from a list, put them into a new list, and then repeating that process until the I've reached the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the trick:

```
# assuming your list is named "list"
page_size = 10
list_pages = []
i = 0
while i <= len(list):
    list_pages.append(list[i : i + page_size])
    i += page_size
```

You can, of course, change the assingment to do whatever you want with the new list

Comment: Hi, I tried putting this into a function, and after running it, it just prints out "None". What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help @skrause

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing your code; can you please post it?